# Do #ifndef prevent defining a function twice when linking two object file?

Tags: c++, linker, object-files

I have two class implementations (`.cpp files`)

They both need a function which was implemented in a `header`(.h) file. Both the .cpp files include the .h file. After compilation, the two `.cpp` files become two `.o` files.

Do the function be defined twice when linking the two object files?

Can `#ifndef` prevent this situation?

I used `#ifndef` but I got the following message,

```
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: By "implemented in a header," do you actually mean that it was implemented - body code and all? Or do you mean it was simply declared in the header? Are the two cpp files perhaps attempting to provide implementations of the same function from the .h?

Answer (score 5):

You must understand the difference between a function *declaration* (a statement that a function with a given name and signature exists) and a function *definition* (the code that determines what the function actually does).

If you *define* the function in the header, then the function will be defined in each object file, and you will get a conflict when you try to link them together; `#ifndef` will not solve this problem.

There will be no such problem if you *declare* the function in the header, and *define* it in a source file (which must be compiled into an object, and linked with the objects that use it). In this simple case, `#ifndef` is not needed.

For example, the function `foo` can be declared in `foo.h`:

```
int foo(int);
```

and defined in `foo.cpp`:

```
int foo(int n)
{
  return(n+3);
}
```

The `#ifndef` macro solves a different problem.

Comment: Thank you. As a result, even though we only need some functions rather than classes, we need both .h and .cpp. Why my IDE only give me a .h file when I add a header? (IDE give me .h and .cpp when I choose to create a class)

Comment: @user2261693: I don't know, it sounds like a shortcoming in the IDE. But you cannot expect an IDE to make all decisions for you.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Beta's answer, you can *define* a free function inside a header file which will be included in multiple translation units, by using the `inline` keyword. Consider this:

```
// Foo.h

int foo(){return 1;}

// UsesFoo1.cpp

#include "Foo.h"
int usesFoo2(){return foo();}

// UsesFoo2.cpp

#include "Foo.h"
int usesFoo1(){return foo();}

// Main.cpp

#include <iostream>
int usesFoo1();
int usesFoo2();

int main()
{
   std::cout << usesFoo1() + usesFoo2() << std::endl;
}
```

This produces a linker error because `int foo()` is defined in two separate translation units. However, no error is generated if you add the `inline` keyword here:

```
// Foo.h

inline int foo(){return 1;}
```

Note: functions defined inside class definitions are implicitly have the `inline` keyword, so you can omit it there.